# Replace an image in code behind for Asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a page, which is called from 2 different functions. For each function, the page has to be display different image. I have 2 images.

On the aspx page, code is like this. Please help me out how to display different image for different functions!! Thanks Guys!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have an image on your ASPX page like this

```
<asp:Image id="myImage" runat="server" />
```

You can dynamically change the `ImageUrl` property of the image on the server-side like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Your logic to detect which image to display goes here
    var imageUrl = GetMyImageUrl();

    myImage.ImageUrl = imageUrl;
}
```